# Convert .grib2 in triangular grid to regular grid

Tags: rasterio, python-3, grib-2

I have ICON datasets (.grib2.bz2 file format) from Deutscher Wetterdienst (DWD) in triangular grid that I would like to transform to a regular grid. Currently, I run the following statement in my Python script:

```
subprocess.call(['./transform.sh', blobName])
```

In this bash script I have the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
bzip2 -d ${1}

export in_file=${1//.bz2/}
export out_file=${in_file//icosahedral_single-level/world_0125x0125}

time cdo -f grb2 remap,settings.txt,weights.nc ${in_file} ${out_file}
```

DWD provides details on how to achieve this [here](https://www.dwd.de/DE/leistungen/opendata/help/modelle/Opendata_cdo_EN.pdf?__blob=publicationFile&v=3). I would like to improve my script in two ways:

1. Run everything in python itself
2. Do not use physical files

This means I would like to download the .grib2.bz2 file in memory and produce the output in memory so I can store it in Azure Blob Storage.

Is this feasible? Maybe with rasterio?
For 1) I could use python [cdo](https://code.mpimet.mpg.de/projects/cdo/wiki/Cdo%7Brbpy%7D) but this does not solve 2) as far as I know. I was also not able to run cdo on Python 3.X version.